How to evaluate the condition of the ProjectPropertyGroupElement into a bool?
I'm using the MSBuild APIs.
I have a ProjectRootElement instance:
var project = ProjectRootElement.Create(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(input)));

Then, I iterate over all PropertyGroups:
foreach (ProjectPropertyGroupElement group in project.PropertyGroups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(group.Condition);
}

When I access the .Condition property of ProjectPropertyGroupElement, I'm assuming that this will return a boolean, which specifies the evaluated value of the condition.
For example, I have a PropertyGroup here:
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(UpdateVersion) >= $(CurrentVersion) and $(Status.ToLower()) == 'newupdate'">
    <UpdateVersion>158</UpdateVersion>
    <CurrentVersion>144</CurrentVersion>
    <Status>NewUpdate</Status>
    <Reporting>
        <UpdateAvailable />
    </Reporting>
</PropertyGroup>

When I access the .Condition property, I assume that this will evaluate the Condition attribute of PropertyGroup and return the result as a boolean. The condition attribute checks if 'UpdateVersion' >= 'CurrentVersion' and 'Status' equals to 'NewUpdate', which should return true. Instead, the Condition property returns the raw condition value:
$(UpdateVersion) >= $(CurrentVersion) and $(Status.ToLower()) == 'newupdate'

Is there a way to evaluate the .Condition property of ProjectPropertyGroupElement into a boolean?

Microsoft.Build.Evaluation ?

@Sinatr Thanks, I looked into the Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project methods but couldn't really find a method that can evaluate a condition into a boolean.

For class Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectPropertyGroupElement the Condition Property is a string which is the text of the Condition attribute and not the result of evaluating the expression that the text represents.

The Microsoft.Build.Evaluation will have the results of evaluation of the project -- which won't help because the property groups will have been evaluated. I suspect you have an XY problem. Can you explain why you need to know the boolean result of the Condition attribute?

FYI properties don't support child elements. <PropertyGroup><Reporting><UpdateAvailable /></Reporting</PropertyGroup> creates a $(Reporting) property with the string value <UpdateAvailable />. I'd suggest just using <PropertyGroup><Reporting>UpdateAvailable</Reporting</PropertyGroup>. If this string is being used to write an XML file, creating an element with the name in the $(Reporting) property can be done at that time.

@JonathanDodds Thanks, I figured it out based on your explanation - I should use .GetPropertyValue(string) method instead, and if it returns an empty string, that's when I know PropertyGroup's condition returned false. And yes, it definitely was an XY problem - initially, I thought the PropertyGroup's Condition has to be evaluated manually. If you post an answer to this question with the same explanation, I will accept it.

In the Microsoft.Build.Construction namespace the ProjectPropertyGroupElement class represents a PropertyGroup element in a project and the Condition Property is a string which is the text of the Condition attribute and not the result of evaluating the expression that the text represents.
The Microsoft.Build.Evaluation namespace classes are used to represent the results of evaluation of the project -- which won't help because the property groups will have been evaluated. However, you can retrieve and check the value of a given property for the evaluated project with the Project.GetPropertyValue(string name) method.
Note that the -getProperty command line switch can be used to retrieve a property value.
e.g.:
msbuild -getProperty:UpdateVersion

or
dotnet msbuild -getProperty:UpdateVersion

Also note that properties don't support child elements.
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Reporting>
      <UpdateAvailable />
    </Reporting>
  </PropertyGroup>

The above example creates a $(Reporting) property with the string value "<UpdateAvailable />". It does not create an XML fragment.
If an XML file is being created, creating an element with the name in the $(Reporting) property can be done at that time and the property definition can be simplified to:
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Reporting>UpdateAvailable</Reporting>
  </PropertyGroup>

